# How to create or clone reports in Apex

Tags: apex, reporting, metadata-api

I need to display data **dynamically** from reports, depending on records.

The url hacking way (pv0 and stuff) doesn't work in lightning experience, so I am wondering how I could achieve this in it.

I thought about creating reports from apex, it would be great to use a "template" report, and creatin a new one from it with record-specific parameters, still I couldn't manage to find any good documentation nor code sample to implement such a thing.

The [Salesforce Reports and Dashboards API via Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_intro.htm) documentation only provides information on how to retrieve reports data, but not if it is possible to create some using apex.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually managed to clone reports and dashboards using Apex and the [Metadata Api](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/) provided by Andrew Fawcett on Github.

Just wanted to share it, here's [the issue where you can find the code samples](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/147) used.

Edit: As of API version 34, you can also use the [Analytics API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_clone_report.htm) for cloning, but you need to do a callout.